# Windows 10 IoT Wrong Time

Tags: windows-iot

my issues is that when I boot my pi the time is always off. Now I have already set the time to my location I am in Eastern standard time(US), I have also tried to manually set the time using Powershell(PS) with remote access. Does daylight savings time play a role? Regardless if it is or not the clock is still not off by a complete hour and is something along the lines of being off by two hours and fifteen minutes.

Answer (score 5):

The Raspberry Pi **does not have an onboard RTC (Real Time Clock).**

This means that when the Pi is powered off, and back on again, it thinks that it is the same time as when it was powered off. (Assuming is has a `fake-hwclock` which most OS's contain.) Because it does not have a clock that ticks while it is off.

There are two ways to combat this:

### **1. NTP [Network Time Protocol**

The easiest one by far. Just connect the Pi to a network, either via Ethernet or Wifi, when the Pi boots it will pull the current time from the network.

### 2. I2C RTC [Real Time Clock]

The best method for portable projects, or when a network is not an option. You can purchase an I2C RTC [here](http://thepihut.com/products/mini-rtc-module-for-raspberry-pi?variant=758601217) or [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-DIY-DS3231-Precision-RTC-Clock-Module-Memory-Module-for-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi-/371312488218?hash=item5673f2ef1a:g:m0AAAOSwcwhVOgnR) (if you don't want to/can't buy it from these sellers you can just search [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=ds3231%20raspberry%20pi&es_th=1) on Google). There is a great tutorial for this at [The Pi Hut](http://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi) **for Raspbian systems**. It works by a tiny battery powering a small clock on the module, and when your Pi boots, a script is ran that pulls the current time from this clock.

---

I am currently using both NTP and an RTC on multiple Raspberry Pis and I can say they both work great.

Comment: This is my fault for not making the question more clear. My raspberry pi is displaying the wrong time, RTC doesn't seem like a option(don't have the money), I already have my pi connected to my companies network through Ethernet that is how I am able to connect to my Pi through PS, however the time is still not adjusting to the networks time.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to use an external Web Service to get the time if your router does not have your appropriate time-zone available.